# Adding a condition to query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that works grate. How ever I need to add one condition.
I want to get a documents that also  have the field "marked" :"true"

This is my query.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "min_score": 0.6,
  "query": { 
      "bool": {
          "should": [
              { "multi_match" : {
                  "fields" : ["_all"],
                  "query" : " Test " ,
                  "fuzziness" : "1.5" ,
                  "prefix_length" : "2" 
              }
            }
          ],
          "must": { "bool": { "must": [
              { "terms": { "language.id":["1"] }},
              { "term": { "forbidden":"false" }}
         ]
        }}}
   },  "sort": [{ "_score": { "order": "desc"}} ]
}
```

I have been trying ti add a should clause after both must clauses. 
Where can I put this condition?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "_all"
            ],
            "query": " Test ",
            "fuzziness": "1.5",
            "prefix_length": "2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "language.id": [
              "1"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "forbidden": "false"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "marked": "true"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This brings me the only document that has "marked": "true".
I'm pretty sure this needs to be in a "should". However wherever I try It gives error or just the one document.

Comment: you were not getting it in the query you have posted ? since there was no condition for marked, you must be getting both true and false. i didnt understand your question i guess